# round-minimum in siunitx when input is zero

Tags: siunitx, r

I use `siunitx` and its `round-minimum=0.001` function. I have a table with input `0` because `knitr` exports only numbers up to a certain decimal. However, `0` is not shown as `<0.001` but as `0`. According to the vignette,

[image: vignette]

from which I understand that any number below the threshold is shown as `<threshold`. As far as I understand, this should include 0. Does anyone know how to get it to do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{ table-alignment=right, 
          round-mode=places, 
          round-precision=3,
          round-minimum=0.001, 
          table-format=<1.3}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S}
0.0004  \\
0
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Because 0 is not rounded number, but exactly zero?

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: Your problem is `knitr`, not `siunitx`. If `siunitx`  receive zero from `kniter` how should it  know if the number is zero or rounded number to zero? You need to solve the problem at `kniter` or manually correct "zeros" in tables.

Comment: But why would `siunitx` need to know? I understood `round-minimum=0.001`such that any input, rounded or not, that is smaller than `0.001` is shown as `<0.001` Somehow, this does not work with `0`.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Please read again explanation in `siunitx` documentation. BTW, how you will imagine to distinguish between zero and number rounded to zero?

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding. I have posted the section from the vignette above. My reading is that it's irrelevant whether input to `siunitx` is already rounded. Say it is fed with `0.000004`. This number could be rounded already and still `siunitx` applies its algorithm and shows it as `<0.001`. Why would this be different for `0`? Can you explain to me where I am misunderstanding things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `siunitx`  manual:

> round-minimum
>
> There are cases in which rounding will result in the
>   number reaching zero. It may be desirable to show such results as
>   below a threshold value. This can be achieved by setting round-minimum
>   to the threshold value. There will be no effect when rounding to a
>   number of significant figures as it is not possible to obtain the
>   value zero in these cases.

For illustration an example based on your MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ table-alignment=right,
          round-mode=places,
          round-precision=3,
          round-minimum=0.001,
          table-format=<1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l | S | l}
input data  & {showed data} & comment           \\  \hline
0.135 678   & 1.135 678     & rounded           \\
0.000 056   & 0.000 056     & rounded to zero   \\
0.000 5     & 0.000 5       & rounded           \\
0.000 4     & 0.000 4       & rounded to zero   \\
0.000 468   & 0.000 468     & rounded to zero   \\
0.000 000   & 0.000 000     & not rounded       \\
0           & 0             & integer, not rounded 
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from above illustration, option `round-minimum=0.001` take the action, when input number is rounded to zero, otherwise is active only standard mechanism for rounding.

In your case this meaning the following: if input data from `kniter` for example have 6 digits, which are already rounded, than `siunitx`  this data due to option `table-format=<1.3` show as numbers with 1 integer and 3 decimal digits, where the last decimal digits are due to `round-precision=3` is rounded, when necessary. In the case, when `siunitx` will them round to zero, they will be due to option `round-minimum=0.001` shown as 0.001. ON this way is possible to distinguish, when input numbers are equal to zero and when they are rounded to zero.

Comment: Okay, so it only applies the algorithm when it would be 0, not otherwise? I now see my mistake but I do believe such behavior is problematic: If `round-minimum=0.02` and input is `0.005`, this gets rounded up to `0.01` which is smaller than the threshold but gets shown rather than converted to `<0.02`. I then write my own macro that applies a minimum threshold to all values --- a functionality that I feel would fit well into `siunitx`.

Comment: @bumblebee, well, than you should write to package author about your opinion. To me this feature is very reasonable and deliberate.